# How was Dr. Khanna able to fix QT?

Tags: movie, love-story-2050

Dr. Khanna was a great scientist and inventor of time machine, but how could he fix technology of future?

**Some Details:** QT is an Android with Artificial Intelligence which Dr. Khanna found in 2050. Such Androids weren't in existence in 2008 (time of Dr. Khanna; from when he jumped to 2050). Dr. Khanna fixed QT within few hours.

Comment: <Moderator removed comments> Keep it civil and avoid xenophobia. This is an international site.

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/is-community-mistaken-about-too-localized-vtc-cause)

Comment: Three cheers for finally getting a mod who removes comments when it is sorely needed, and ONLY when it's actually sorely needed.

Comment: @Kevin Since I feel that you're basically calling me racist, let me clarify. He asked why someone was taking it from a US perspective, instead of Wordly perspective. It's like asking a question in `insert language` then wondering why they are taking it from an `insert nationality` perspective instead of an `insert 2nd separate language & nationality`.

Comment: @MadBurn - this site is not "for American works only". It's not even "for works in English" only. The only restriction is that the questions are in English (and i'm not even 100% sure of that to be honest). And there's no "perspective" on this question or the work - it's a question about the fictional premise, not a cultural/linguistic one.

Comment: @MadBurn English is an international language. That's why this international site has chosen it.

Comment: @MadBurn I wasn't singling anyone out, and xenophobia is about countries, not races. You certainly aren't the first on this site to make such statements, you just happened to be the one participating in this conversation.

Comment: And @DVK, yes, questions are required to be in English except on language-specific sites, e.g. [German.SE], [French.SE].

Comment: @Kevin Just a note, without wanting to enter the actual discussion: Merriam-Webster defines [xenophobia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophobia?show=0&t=1373012540) as "fear and hatred of strangers or foreigners or of anything that is strange or foreign".

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the movie, so I'm likely to get some things wrong when referencing it.  But the basic premise - fixing something you haven't been trained in - is something I do regularly at work, only I do it with programming languages rather than hardware (which I assume was the problem with QT).

To invent the time machine Dr. Khanna must have been skilled in mechanical and electrical engineering.  Very skilled to invent something like that - he must have understood the theory very well along with practical application.  Probably even wrote the software to run the time machine.

When presented with non-working technology you don't understand, the first thing to do is to dig in and identify something that fits with the theory you know.  For example, power sources are likely to be easily distinguishable even in future tech, as they have a unique purpose.

From there, you expand outwards.  Poke and prod until something happens, then put it back the way it was.  Then repeat with something else.  It's possible to find patterns and make connections in your mind pretty quickly, even if you don't completely know how it works internally.  Once the broken part is identified, fixing it is often easier - in the process of finding it, you probably also have an idea about how it was broken.

For a simplified idea of what this is like, when was the last time you read the user manual for *any* of your electronics cover-to-cover to learn how it works?  It's much simpler to just dive in, because prior experience has given you the knowledge to use the newer, more advanced model, even if it takes a bit of extra time to find all its features.

That said, I do agree that for technology advancement over 42 years, a few hours was rather quick.

(Unless it was painfully obvious after digging in, like a visible crack in the power supply, which you could just go buy a replacement for at the store.  We do sometimes get lucky like that!)

Answer (score 0):

No in-universe explanation
I don't see a way you can fix a machine that is 42 years ahead of your time. Just looking at the schematics and logical reverse engineering isn't good enough. Take for e.g - Would an engineer from the 70's be able to fix a broken modern day sports car? The concept of an ECU wasn't even in existence back then. 
Similarly, it is nearly impossible for any scientist, no matter how brilliant they are, to fix a technology almost 50 years ahead of their time, and that too in a matter of hours.

P.S. it seems like a page taken out of BTTF where Doc Brown fixes his own DeLorean. But he had also supplied the schematics along with the car.

Comment: If the modern day sports car had a vacuum leak, broken timing chain, or other *mechanical* problem, any decent mechanic from the 70s (or earlier) could probably fix it with a bit of tinkering. Maybe not something gone wrong with the ECU, but plenty of other things can break a car.

Comment: @Geobits - that was an equivalent example. An android is a lot more complex than a car...

Comment: Sure, but my point was that it just depends on what was wrong with it. If there was something wrong with a class of circuit/widget that hadn't been invented yet, then I agree that it's not as plausible. For many other problems (mechanical, basic circuitry, etc), it might not be *easy*, but it should be possible.